# Can I trace all the functions/methods executing in a python script?

Tags: python, debugging, trace

Is there a way to programmatically trace the execution of all python functions/methods? I would like to see what arguments each of them was called with. I really mean all, I'm not interested in a trace decorator.

In Ruby, I could alias the method I wanted and add the extra behaviour there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [trace](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html) module.

You can also use it via the command line:

```
python -m trace --help
```

Comment: how does this work in python? I know in ruby what I have to do to make it work, I would like to know what python does for me.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Are you interested to know how the tracing mechanism works or how to use the trace module?

Comment: I'm interested in how tracing in python works. Just the general idea of what python does behind the scene.

Comment: In a sentence, the trace modules adds handlers via sys.settrace (which sets the system's trace function).  The docs give a pretty overview of what's involved with this: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the mechanism.

Comment: python -m trace does not appear able to show function parameters