# How can I trace the functions call stack in a Python script?

Tags: python

I am trying to debug some code written long ago, and due to the scarce documentation would like a way to trace the functions being called from execution to final output, possibly with which parameters they were called with. A sort of `sys.traceback` but in the case of no errors. It would also be nice to get the report as a HTML or another exportable format. 
Something along the lines of:

`main()->class->run()->getData()->saveData()`

I already looked at [Can I trace all the functions/methods executing in a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005665/can-i-trace-all-the-functions-methods-executing-in-a-python-script) but it doesn't answer the question as functions are not reportd.

Comment: [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/trace.html) with the `--trace` option *does* report function calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you need [settrace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function

**CODE**

```
import sys

def traceit(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "call":
        co = frame.f_code
        func_name = co.co_name
        print("event:", event,"of function",func_name)
    return traceit

def main():
    print ("In main")
    for i in range(5):
        print (i, i*3)
    print ("Done.")


sys.settrace(traceit)
main()
```

**OUT PUT**

```
event: call of function main
In main
0 0
1 3
2 6
3 9
4 12
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pycallgraph`](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.org/en/master/) or another "call graph" visualization tool.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. While it may not provide a lot of added value in a (simple) script, for larger projects, such a visualization tool can be invaluable. Exceptionally useful in development!